# Terraform destroy error 'Instance cannot be destroyed' and 'Failed getting S3 bucket'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm currently trying to destroy a workspace, I know that there are some buckets that have a 'do not destroy' type tag applied to them, so when I run `terraform destroy` for the first time, I got `Instance cannot be destroyed` error for two buckets:

```
Resource module.xxx.aws_s3_bucket.xxx_bucket has
lifecycle.prevent_destroy set, but the plan calls for this resource to be
destroyed. To avoid this error and continue with the plan, either disable
lifecycle.prevent_destroy or reduce the scope of the plan using the -target
flag.
```

so I navigate to the AWS console and delete them manually then tried to run `terraform destroy` again, then it's complaining about one of the buckets that I've removed manually: `Failed getting S3 bucket: NotFound: Not Found`, the other one seems fine.

Does anyone know how to resolve this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you removed the resource with an action external to a modification in the Terraform state (in this situation a bucket removed manually through the console), then you need to update the Terraform state correspondingly. You can do this with the `terraform state` subcommand. Given your listed example of a resource named `module.xxx.aws_s3_bucket.xxx_bucket`, it would appear like:

```
terraform state rm module.xxx.aws_s3_bucket.xxx_bucket
```

You can find more info in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/rm.html).

Comment: Thanks. I actually modified the `lifecycle.prevent_destroy` to 'false' then re-apply, then tried destroy and it worked!